# Cypress Drag and Drop for Pseudo element

Tags: drag-and-drop, cypress

Source element

```html
<span class="Multiterm Multiterm-"> Ready Messages</span>
```

Before I drop the source element to the target element, it looks like this:

```html
<div class="react-grid-layout LightTheme dashboardGridLayout" style="height: 5px;"></div>
```

After I drop the source element to the target element, it looks like this:

```html
<div class="react-grid-layout LightTheme dashboardGridLayout" style="height: 365px;">
  <div id="1" class="react-grid-item LightTheme widget draggableArea react-draggable cssTransforms react-resizable" data-grid="[object Object]" data-coordinate="2:1" style="height: 265px; position: absolute; transform: translate(180px, 90px) !important; width: 355px !important;">
    <div class="widgetTopDiv">
      <span class="LightTheme widgetSpan">
        <span class="Multiterm Multiterm-"> Ready Messages</span>
      </span>
      <span class="LightTheme filterSpan">
        <img src="./static/media/filter_applied.4d67f99c.svg" class="LightTheme widgetFilterIcon" draggable="false">
      </span>
      <span class="actionDeleteSpan">
        <img id="1" src="./static/media/copy.5d595a98.svg" class="LightTheme widgetCopyIcon" draggable="false">
        <img src="./static/media/Edit_123.b70c7de2.svg" class="LightTheme widgetEditIcon" draggable="false">
        <img src="./static/media/close.ae62c28e.svg" class="LightTheme widgetDeleteIcon" draggable="false">
      </span>
    </div>
    <div id="chartWidget_1" class="chartDataItem">
      <span class="settingsIcon">
        <img class="LightTheme settingsIcon" src="./static/media/No data loaded.612d838a.svg" draggable="false">
      </span>
    </div>
    <span class="react-resizable-handle react-resizable-handle-se"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

My spec file to test this scenario is:

```javascript
cy.visit("link-to-site")
cy.get('#Username').type('user-name')
cy.contains('Continue').click()
cy.get('#Password').type('password')
cy.get("button[value='login']").click()
cy.wait(10000)
cy.get(".newDashboard.LightTheme.LiButton_DefaultClass").click()
cy.wait(3000)
cy.get("#menuExpanIcon").click()
const drag_source = "span[id='24_dashboardKpiMenu'] span span[class='Multiterm Multiterm-']"
const drag_target = ".react-grid-layout.LightTheme.dashboardGridLayout"
cy.wait(1000)

const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
cy.get(drag_source).trigger('dragstart', {
            dataTransfer
});
cy.get(drag_target).trigger('drop', {force: true}, {
            dataTransfer
})
```

The test runs perfectly on Cypress and passes, however the drag operation doesn't occur in the UI.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the test is closing early, before the UI changes have completed.

At the moment you are using the eyeball method of assertion, but that's not the way to perform an automated test.

If you add an assertion after the drag operation, to confirm it was successful, the test will be much more reliable.

```js
cy.get(drag_source).trigger('dragstart', {dataTransfer})
cy.get(drag_target).trigger('drop', {force: true}, {dataTransfer})
cy.get(drag_target).find('.widgetTopDiv')
```

By the way, replace all `cy.wait(3000)` with other assertions for elements that are changed after the click actions.

In general, every action you take in the test should have a corresponding confirmation query, following the **Arrange/Act/Assert** pattern.